# Cannot Turn on laptop Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wireless-adapter, wireless-card

I recently upgraded the RAM in my dad's computer (Lenovo ThinkPad E545) because he was complaining that it was slow. Everything worked fine for a little while, then his WiFi died on him.

Windows 10 thinks that a hardware switch is off and all attempts to run the troubleshooter simply tell me to turn the switch back on.  All attempts to turn on the switch have been fruitless, it does nothing.

I've re-seated the RAM, reinstalled the old RAM, reseated the Wi-Fi card,  disconnected and reconnected the antennae cables, checked the BIOS and the device manager to ensue that the card is being recognized (it is), reinstalled Windows,  and even booted into Fedora Linux from a USB drive (and experienced similar issues to Windows).

So I'm pretty sure now it's some sort of hardware issue (feel free to interject here). But what could it be? Again,  the Wi-Fi card is recognized by the computer, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

--- Edit ---

I've changed the Wi-Fi card and the issue remains unchanged.

Here's the output of `lspci -vvv`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8450G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 34
    Region 0: Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at f0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 33
    Region 0: Memory at f0344000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff [empty]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff [size=1M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f0200000-f02fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff [empty]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f0100000-f01fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0400000-00000000f05fffff [size=2M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f0348000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f034a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3118 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 3124 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 3110 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 3120 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 3100 [size=16]
    Region 5: Memory at f034e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f034d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f034e900 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f034c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f034e800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=slow >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f0340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 510a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle+ MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-00000fff [empty]
    Memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff [empty]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff [empty]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5100
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
    Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 0179
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 35
    Region 0: I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5100
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 31
    Region 0: Memory at f0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Comment: Perhaps the wifi card is dead. A USB wifi [adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_8?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb+wifi+adapter&sprefix) can solve this problem.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the output of the "lspci" command in Fedora (or equivalent command in Windows)? Also, if you have another laptop available, try using its wifi card on his computer and his wifi card in the other laptop. Oh, and try resetting the CMOS (take out the RTC battery and wait 8-15 hours)

Comment: @AntonLiakhovitch I've edited my question with the requested output. I also tried another card. However, it seems like ThinkPads are configured in BIOS/EFI to only work with an authorized wifi card. Funny because the laptop I swapped it with is also a ThinkPad (albeit a bit older, a T510). So sadly that's a no-go. I'm about to yank the RTC battery now and I'll report back after work

Answer (score 0):

No way of turning Wi-Fi on with this model on Fedora. Since it needs the combination FN+Wifi button. It is already challenging to make that work, after a while when I managed to have somehow access to the card, drivers can't really cope with this computer. I tried everything; If you want to troubleshoot it, you better stick to Windows.

Comment: Actually, the FN button has nothing to do with it. Fedora still recognizes the buttons as usual. I can use the other buttons, such as volume and brightness control in Fedora just fine. And the Wifi toggle button does indicate that it's at least trying to turn on the Wifi